# Javascripts debug error in Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers Packages)

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have downloaded Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers Packages. I tried to create a JavaScript project and a `.html` file inside it. When I tried to debug it by right click it and selected "Chrome and Chromium Debugger" to debug JavaScript inside the `.html` file. This error prompt out with the message:

> "Unable to run Chrome / Chromium. Verify you have a configured Chrome / Chromium runtime environment and try again."

May you know how to solve it? I have spent a week to struggle with it.

Comment: I found the cause. Please refer to this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1FmC7aQzbk You should go to  Eclipse Preferences → JavaScript → Runtimes and define Chrome / Chromium there.

Answer (score 5):

I found the cause. Please refer to this link youtube.com/watch?v=l1FmC7aQzbk You should go to Eclipse Preferences → JavaScript → Runtimes and define Chrome / Chromium there.